# What does () mean in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have the following function in `Swift 3`

```
func fetchOrders(_ completionHandler: (_ orders: [Order]) -> Void)
  {
    ordersStore.fetchOrders { (orders: () throws -> [Order]) -> Void in
      do {
        let orders = try orders()
        completionHandler(orders)
      } catch {
        completionHandler([])
      }
    }
  }
```

1. What does `_ completionHandler` argument in `fetchOrders` mean?
2. What does `(orders: () throws -> [Order])` mean?

PS : I am new to `iOS` and `Swift`

Comment: Reading the chapter "Functions" in the Swift Reference book might be helpful  ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's quite a lot in here, so we'll break it down one piece at a time:

```
func fetchOrders(_ completionHandler: (_ orders: [Order]) -> Void)
```

- This is a function called `fetchOrders`.
- It has one parameter (`completionHandler`) and returns nothing.
- The first `_` indicates that there is no "external name" of the first parameter. That is, you do not have to label it (in fact, you cannot). (For subtle reasons that don't really matter here, I believe the author made a mistake using `_` there, and I would not have done that.)
- The `completionHandler` is the "internal name," what the parameter is called inside the function.
- The type of `completionHandler` is `(_ orders: [Order]) -> Void`. We'll break that down now.

  - This value is a closure that takes an `[Order]` (array of `Order`) and returns `Void`. Informally this means "returns nothing" but literally means it returns the empty tuple `()`.
  - The `_ orders:` syntax is in practice a comment. In principle the `_` is an external name (but that's the only legal external name for a closure), and `orders` is an internal name, but in reality, closures parameters do not have names in any meaningful way, so this is purely informational.
  - I believe this is a poor use of the closure parameter commenting system. Since `orders` tells us nothing more than `[Order]`, I would have omitted it, and made the type just `([Order]) -> Void`.

Now we'll turn to the next line:

```
ordersStore.fetchOrders { (orders: () throws -> [Order]) -> Void in
```

- This calls the `fetchOrders` method on `ordersStore`. We can tell from this code that `fetchOrders` takes a closure parameter. This is called "trailing closure" syntax in Swift, and is why I would not have used the `_` for our closure. With trailing closure syntax, the external name of the parameter is not needed.
- The author has provided type information here that probably wasn't necessary, but we can explore it anyway. This could likely have been written as just `{ orders in`, but then the reader would probably have been surprised by this somewhat unusual code.

  - We have been passed a closure called `orders` that takes nothing and returns `[Order]` or throws an error. Basically this is a way to say that `fetchOrders` might fail.
  - The author is working around an awkwardness in Swift's `throws` system, which does not have a natural way to express an asynchronous action that might fail. This is one way to fix it; you pass a throwing (i.e. a possibly failing) function. I don't favor this approach, I favor using a `Result` enum for this case because I think it scales better and avoids possible unintended side effects, but that's a debatable point (and the Swift community hasn't really decided how to deal with this common problem).

This all leads us to:

```
  do {
    let orders = try orders()
    completionHandler(orders)
  } catch {
    completionHandler([])
  }
```

- This is where the `orders` closure is evaluated. (This is very important; if `orders` has side effects, this is when they occur, which may be on a different queue than was intended. That's one reason I don't favor this pattern.) If the closure succeeds, we return its result, otherwise we return `[]` in the `catch` below.

  - In this *particular* case, the `throws` approach is slightly silly, because it's silently flattened into `[]` without even a log message. If we don't care about the errors, then failure should have just returned `[]` to start with and not messed with `throws`. But it's possible that other callers do check the errors.
- In either case, we call the `completionHandler` closure with our result, chaining this back to our original caller.

This do/catch block could have been more simply written as:

```
let completedOrders = try? orders() ?? []
completionHandler(completedOrders)
```

This makes it clearer that we're ignoring errors by turning it into an optional, and avoids code duplication of the call to `completionHandler`.

(I just add the extra `let` binding to make the code a little easier to read; it isn't needed.)

Comment: This couldn't have been explained better.

Comment: Can someone explain, how or why this pattern can have the completion handler end up on a different queue?

Comment: @Jay On a different queue than what? (There is no "current queue" in GCD. This is a very common misunderstanding of how queues work.) If the method performs work on a background thread (a thread is not a queue), it will likely execute the completion handler on that thread when it completes. Dispatching to a queue requires extra complexity; either you need to pass it a queue, or it has to promise some specific queue (such as the main queue). The former is somewhat common in Cocoa. The latter is more common in 3rd party frameworks, but is often undesirable.

Comment: But often methods just call the completion handler when done, and that will execute it on a fairly random thread. It's up to the caller to decide if a specific queue is needed and to dispatch if appropriated.

Comment: You wrote "(This is very important; if orders has side effects, this is when they occur, which may be on a different queue than was intended. That's one reason I don't favor this pattern.)", so I was just curious what this actually meant.

Comment: Ah; that's a different question than I thought you were asking. The problem is that you may have a queue that synchronizes access to some property, or you may expect all accesses to that property occur on some thread (usually the main thread). If you create a closure in that context, and then hand it back, the closure may be evaluated (executed) in some other context. For example, it may be executed on the main thread, which isn't supposed to access that property. This lack of control over the evaluation context makes this approach a little dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

The `completionHandler` argument means that the expected parameter (named `completionHandler`) must be a function that takes a list of `Order` objects and does not return any value.

Answer (score 2):

`completionHandler` is the a variable name. In this specific example, this variable is a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)). You know is a callback function because `(orders: [Order]) -> Void` is it's data type; in this particular case, said data type is a function that receives an array of `Order` objects in a variable `_orders` and doesn't have a return value (the `Void` part).

TL;DR:

1. it's the variable name, of type:
2. function which receives an array of `Order` as a parameter and acts as a callback.